# Twitter bootstrap modal not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I am new to Twitter Bootstrap. I am working on a modal panel, but it is not being displayed. It fades the screen, but the modal itself does not appear. I have checked the error console, and there are no errors.

My code is inside the `<head>` tag; I include the scripts like:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $ruadmin ?>js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo $ruadmin ?>js/tablesorter/jquery.tablesorter.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo $ruadmin ?>js/tablesorter/tables.js"></script>
```

Modal page:

```
<a data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal" class="btn btn-primary btn-large">Launch demo modal</a>

<!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
    <h3 id="myModalLabel">Welcome</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <p> Hello </p>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I had bootstrap.js and bootstrap.min.js added via bundleconfig in my asp.net MVC project, and to witness it all work well after removing bootstrap.min.js and keeping only bootstrap.js

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You need use the `data-target` tag.

Try to replace the `href="#myModal"` attribute with `data-target="#myModal"`.
Besides, you have put a `hide` class, I guess it shouldn't be there.

Look at the examples [here](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals)

Comment: yeah it worked. the problem was because of `hide` class.thanks :)

Answer (score 14):

Change this:

```
<a data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal" class="btn btn-primary btn-large">Launch demo modal</a>
```

To this:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-large" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Launch demo modal</button>
```

*(remark that changing `a` tag to `button` tag is not the answer but it is adding the `data-target` and `data-toggle` attribute that does the "work")*

Please look at this example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html >

<html>
<head>
    <title>Bootstrap Modal</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>    
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <!-- Optional theme -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.2/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-large" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Launch demo modal</button>

    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="purchaseLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="purchaseLabel">Purchase</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    sup?
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Purchase</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Changing `a` to `button` will do nothing. The trick is in setting `data-target` attribute. You should highlight that in your answer.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue, I realized i include the JQUERY library after BOOTSTRAP.

Check to see that in your webpage you add/link first JQUERY and then Bootstrap

Answer (score 2):

In case someone run into this problem and none of the above works, I didn't have the css class fade in the class attribute of my modal

I had the div of my modal like this

```
<div class="modal" id="AdvanceSearchModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
```

I added fade class

```
<div class="modal fade" id="AdvanceSearchModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
```

and with this the modal opens again

Answer (score 2):

### Bootstrap Modal doesn't like `Id`'s that start with a `number`.

I had a `UUID` as my `data-target` and it did not work.

```
<button data-target="#7CB2ED35-3AE1-44FD-AEA8-D953E5C953D5">Launch Modal</button>
```

I **solved** it by pre-pend "M-" before all my `UUID`'s so they're still unique:

```
<button data-target="#M-7CB2ED35-3AE1-44FD-AEA8-D953E5C953D5">Launch Modal</button>
```

✌

Comment: Wow, this was so annoying. After looking everywhere, none of these solutions worked until this one. Thank you!