# Bootstrap Modal not working as expected

Tags: bootstrap-modal

I've added bootstrap modal to my website, but it's not working. Someone help me fix it. Thanks.

```
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg">Update</button>

  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myupdate" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">New Update </h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>This is a small modal.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Twitter bootstrap modal not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20472588/twitter-bootstrap-modal-not-working)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Missing your data-toggle and target

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myupdate">Open Small Modal</button>
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to set `data-target` as target `id` of your `modal` and `data-toggle = "modal"` to the `button` on which you want to activate the modal

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" data-target="#myupdate" data-toggle="modal" class="btn btn-info btn-lg">Update</button>

  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myupdate" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">New Update </h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>This is a small modal.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```