# why bootstrap modal hiding impress other buttons?

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4

I have a modal that it contains some buttons that when click on them, show some data. The problem is after this if you click outside the modal, modal is closed but every buttons in the page are disabled and don't working .I don't  know how to find problem.

This codes are just a piece of my code.

```
<div class="container">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>
    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
                <div id=result></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
    $(function() {
    $('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
        $('#result').html('');
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bootstrap Modal not working as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32449800/bootstrap-modal-not-working-as-expected)

Comment: @Pogs no my modal is working and just in a special status that i explained up , blocked clicked event on buttons

Comment: Please add full code